# ReactJS, I want to retrigger an ajax call in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

-I have a Component (let's call it StorageComponent) that get a data(JSON) from a restful api (the request is made in componentDidMount)

-StorageComponent then passes the data to a child component and it will do stuff with other components to display the data and interact with user.

---

-Now there is another hierarchy of components independent of the above.

-This handle some form inputs by users, there is one component for each form input (radio button, checkbox, text, etc). And because every re-render will get rid of any state of the child, I had to use an object literal (call it ModelObject) to store each form input. So whenever a user enter something in a form it will make a call to Modelobject and store it there, the component will also ask for data from ModelObject.

-After The user entered all input he will eventually hit a submit button component in this hierarchy, where it will make a call to ModelObject to do ajax POST to the RestAPI. My problem is here, I would like for ModelComponent to get the data from the RestAPI again, so user will see the updated data. I thought forceUpdate() would work, I thought it would re-trigger rendering and thus componentDidMount in StorageComponent.

So what is the best way to do this. Moreover is there any bad practice mentioned above? Is this enough information?

edit:

the storageComponent hierarchy

```
  var StorageComponent= React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result){
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      this.setState({
        data: result
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Nav dataList={this.state.data} /> //whole bunch of other child component below this one
      </div>
    );
  }
});

  app.storageComponent= React.render(
    <HabitModel source = "/api/listing/user"/>,
    document.getElementById('myDiv')
  );
```

the ModelObject that I've mentioned:

```
      var formModel = {
      newInfo: {
          inputBox: "",
          frequency: "",
          date: "",
          days: []
      },
      addDescription: function(description){
        this.newHabitInfo.description = description;
      },
      addFrequency: function(selection){
        this.newHabitInfo.frequency = selection;
      },
      addDay: function(startDay){
        this.newHabitInfo.startDay = startDay;
      },
      getFrequency: function(){
        return this.newHabitInfo.frequency;
      },

      //this is the function I want the second hierarchy of components to  
      //use to force the storageComponent to do the re-trigger the ajax

      updateHabitListing: function(){
          if(this.validate()){
            app.habitListing.forceUpdate(); 
          }else{
            console.log("form not finish");
          }
      }
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see a watered-down plunker/codepen to get a feel for the structure of your components.

Comment: I added some code, is this good enough? I omitted a lot of stuff cause I think it will just waste your time to read.